# Using listings with output

Tags: listings

I wonder how to get the output of listings with code. Here is my MWE with output. Now I want to output of this listings too. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

---

### Code

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\lstset{ % General setup for the package
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=tb,
    tabsize=4,
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    keepspaces,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{document}
Welcome to \LaTeX.
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

---

### Output

---

[image]

Comment: `tcolorbox` and its `tcblisting` environment, however not with `begin{document` in it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to show the output along with the LaTeX code is to use [the `showexpl` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/showexpl):

[image]

### Notes:

- To adjust the position of the output you can use the `pos=` option: `t`op, `b`ottom, `r`ight, `l`eft, `o`uter, and `i`nner.

### Code:

```
%\RequirePackage{filecontents}% Comment out so that "example.tex" is not overwritten
\begin{filecontents*}{example.tex}
    Here is some \LaTeX code in an 
    \emph{external} file.  
    The input file is not altered in
    terms of line breaks, but the
    output is properly typeset.
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{ % General setup for the package
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=tb,
    tabsize=4,
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    keepspaces,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}

\begin{document}

Use the environment \verb|LTXexample| to show the code and its output:
\medskip
\begin{LTXexample}[width=0.60\linewidth]
\begin{document}
Welcome to \LaTeX.
\end{document}
\end{LTXexample}

\bigskip
To include code from an external file, use \verb|\LTXinputExample|, 
and also applied \verb|pos=r| to have output on right: 
\medskip
\LTXinputExample[width=0.5\linewidth,pos=r]{example.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1): Thanks @Peter for your answer. This is fantastic. Could you guide me how to include code from external file. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208: Have updated solution to show how to include file from an external file.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. Last thing, how to get code on the right and output on the left.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: I encountered two problems. (1)- `Chapter`, `Section` environments will be added to the main document, and (2)- not working for `beamer`. Any thoughts.

Comment: @MYaseen208: I'd recommend you post a new question as that is unrelated to using `listsings` and showing the output.

Answer (score 8):

The `tcolorbox` provides means for nice typesetting and direct output of `listings` `LaTeX` code. There are many conceptual and visual configuration possibilities, see the documentation of [tcolorbox](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf), e.g. in chapter 9 of the current version 3.12.

However, a `\begin{document}....\end{document}` cannot be catched easily. Just relaxing `\begin{document}` etc. is no option. The `document` environment has to be redefined within a group, such that it's capsuled and does not influence the real outer `document` environment. However, this will drop some content defined within a potential `\AtBeginDocument` or `\AtEndDocument`.

In principle any command allowed only in Preamble will break this example.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{ % General setup for the package
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=tb,
    tabsize=4,
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    keepspaces,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}%



\tcbset{listing engine={listings}}
\begin{document}

% Redefine the document environment within a group
\begingroup
\renewenvironment{document}{%
  }{%
 }%

\begin{tcblisting}{}
\begin{document}
Welcome to \LaTeX.
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}

\endgroup
```

\end{document}

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. Wonder how to put code and output into two different boxes.

Comment: @MYaseen208: Do you wonder or did you wonder? The `tcblisting` boxes can be configured individually to contain listing and output, only listing or only output... The settings of `listings` package (your `\lstset` are used, you can change it of course.

Comment: @MYaseen208: Why did you not be more specific about the two boxes? If I would have had more information on that, I could have updated my answer.

Comment: Never mind. I found `tcolorbox` more appealing but have issues with it. I could not figure out how to put code and output into two boxes and was not able to read code from external file (lack of knowledge). Would appreciate if could help me. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208: I'll try tomorrow

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to your answer and help. Much appreciated.